# Image Fade with MouseEnter Event

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, animation

I'm trying to make an image fade in/out when the user hovers over the button. The fadein works when I enter the button but not when I leave it. How can I make this work?

**Animation Code:**

```
Private Sub GreenBg_animation()
        Dim myduration As Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
        Dim da As DoubleAnimation = New DoubleAnimation
        da.Duration = myduration

        Dim sb As Storyboard = New Storyboard
        sb.Duration = myduration
        sb.Children.Add(da)
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da, btn_bg_green)
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, New PropertyPath(OpacityProperty))
        da.From = 0.0
        da.To = 1.0
        da.AutoReverse = True
        sb.Begin()
    End Sub
```

**Button code:**

```
 Private Sub btn_2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs) Handles btn_2.MouseEnter
            GreenBg_animation()
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another (reverse) animation on `MouseExit`, if you thought that `AutoReverse` would do that for you you are mistaken.